# Restaurar wordpress de manera local

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

soy nuevo en wordpress y quiero restaurar un sitio web de manera local, tengo la carpeta wp-content y la base de datos, descarge el wordpress de su pagina lo extraje y todos los archivos de wordpress lo pegue en una carpeta dentro de httdocs de xamp, unicamente reemplaze la carpeta de wp-content, con la que tenia, cree la base de datos e importe la base de datos que tenia. Configure el archivo wp-config.php y trato de acceder al localhost/sitioweb y resulta que me arroja un error 404 de que no se encuentra la pagina. Cual seria el problema de que no pueda levantar la pagina web? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes modificar en la base de datos la table wp_options en el registro "home" y el registro "url" por el dominio local.

Cuando tengas eso, recuerda activar los enlaces permanentes desde el administrador.